# AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'split' Error

Tags: python, ip, scapy

I am running this code in seeking arp request and ether. When I run this it gives me the message

```
 Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "network_scanner.py", line 16, in <module>
    scan('10.0.2.1/24')
  File "network_scanner.py", line 8, in scan
    arp_request.show()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/scapy-2.4.3- 
   py2.7.egg/scapy/packet.py", line 1261, in show
    return self._show_or_dump(dump, indent, lvl, label_lvl)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/scapy-2.4.3- 
   py2.7.egg/scapy/packet.py", line 1235, in _show_or_dump
    reprval = f.i2repr(self, fvalue)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/scapy-2.4.3- 
   py2.7.egg/scapy/fields.py", line 376, in i2repr
    return fld.i2repr(pkt, val)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/scapy-2.4.3- 
   py2.7.egg/scapy/fields.py", line 502, in i2repr
    x = self.i2h(pkt, x)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/scapy-2.4.3- 
   py2.7.egg/scapy/layers/l2.py", line 136, in i2h
    iff = self.getif(pkt)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/scapy-2.4.3- 
   py2.7.egg/scapy/layers/l2.py", line 132, in <lambda>
    self.getif = (lambda pkt: pkt.route()[0]) if getif is None else getif
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/scapy-2.4.3- 
   py2.7.egg/scapy/layers/l2.py", line 400, in route
    fld, dst = fld._find_fld_pkt_val(self, dst)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/scapy-2.4.3- 
   py2.7.egg/scapy/fields.py", line 313, in _find_fld_pkt_val
    if val == dflts_pkt[self.name] and self.name not in pkt.fields:
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/scapy-2.4.3- 
   py2.7.egg/scapy/base_classes.py", line 133, in __eq__
    p2, nm2 = self._parse_net(other)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/scapy-2.4.3- 
   py2.7.egg/scapy/base_classes.py", line 99, in _parse_net
    tmp = net.split('/') + ["32"]
    AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'split'
```

Did I download something wrong or is there a typo? Is there an easy fix to this I am very new to this kind of stuff and I want to grow my knowledge. The code I am running is below

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import scapy.all as scapy

def scan(ip):
    arp_request = scapy.ARP(pdst=ip)
    arp_request.show()
    broadcast = scapy.Ether(dst='ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff')
    broadcast.show()
    arp_request_broadcast = broadcast/arp_request
    print(arp_request_broadcast.summary())
    arp_request_broadcast.show()

scan('10.0.2.1/24')
```

Anyone that can give me a down to earth answer would be appreciated as I am not a sacpy wizard.
Thank You

Comment: This code won't run. The indentation for `scan` is the wrong direction.

Comment: Show the full traceback.

Comment: @EastonAntony you've now fixed the indentation. Thank you

Comment: Is there a easy answer to this nonsense?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `.show()` and `.summary()` on individual packets, not on a group of packets. `10.0.2.1/24` is a subnet of 256 addresses, so when you pass that in to `ARP`, it creates 256 ARP packets.

```py
import scapy.all as scapy

def scan(ip):
    arp_requests = scapy.ARP(pdst=ip)
    for req in arp_requests:
        req.show()
    broadcast = scapy.Ether(dst='ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff')
    broadcast.show()
    arp_request_broadcast = broadcast/arp_requests
    arp_request_broadcast.summary() 
    for req in arp_request_broadcast:
        req.show()

scan('10.0.2.1/24')
```

Your code will not error if you iterate over all of the packets here.

The output will look like this (only last packet of each for-loop shown):

```py
...<truncated>
###[ ARP ]###
  hwtype= 0x1
  ptype= IPv4
  hwlen= None
  plen= None
  op= who-has
  hwsrc= 6c:96:cf:d8:7f:e7
  psrc= 192.168.1.246
  hwdst= 00:00:00:00:00:00
  pdst= 10.0.2.255

...<truncated>
###[ Ethernet ]###
  dst= ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
  src= 6c:96:cf:d8:7f:e7
  type= ARP
###[ ARP ]###
     hwtype= 0x1
     ptype= IPv4
     hwlen= None
     plen= None
     op= who-has
     hwsrc= 6c:96:cf:d8:7f:e7
     psrc= 192.168.1.246
     hwdst= 00:00:00:00:00:00
     pdst= 10.0.2.255
```

Comment: how do you limit the packets

Comment: Limit in what way?

Comment: Like don't I have it where it shows 1/24 not 255 of them?

Comment: Yes. This code you posted will work if you use `scan("10.0.2.1")` instead. Your code as written, works with only one IP at a time.

Answer (score 0):

This was a bug in scapy which is fixed now. Your code looks good (yup, you can give an ip range as input to scapy.ARP() ).

> Bug : https://github.com/secdev/scapy/issues/2400

> Fix : https://github.com/secdev/scapy/pull/2395

> Updated code : https://github.com/secdev/scapy

Just update scapy and you might be good to go.

Code :

```
import scapy.all as scapy

def scan(ip):
    arp_requests = scapy.ARP(pdst=ip)
    for req in arp_requests:
        req.show()
    broadcast = scapy.Ether(dst='ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff')
    broadcast.show()
    arp_request_broadcast = broadcast/arp_requests
    arp_request_broadcast.summary()
    for req in arp_request_broadcast:
        req.show()

scan('10.0.2.1/24')
```

Output (only last few packet summary) :

```
###[ ARP ]### 
     hwtype    = 0x1
     ptype     = IPv4
     hwlen     = None
     plen      = None
     op        = who-has
     hwsrc     = 08:00:27:46:c6:d8
     psrc      = 10.0.2.7
     hwdst     = 00:00:00:00:00:00
     pdst      = 10.0.2.253

###[ Ethernet ]### 
  dst       = ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
  src       = 08:00:27:46:c6:d8
  type      = ARP
###[ ARP ]### 
     hwtype    = 0x1
     ptype     = IPv4
     hwlen     = None
     plen      = None
     op        = who-has
     hwsrc     = 08:00:27:46:c6:d8
     psrc      = 10.0.2.7
     hwdst     = 00:00:00:00:00:00
     pdst      = 10.0.2.254

###[ Ethernet ]### 
  dst       = ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
  src       = 08:00:27:46:c6:d8
  type      = ARP
###[ ARP ]### 
     hwtype    = 0x1
     ptype     = IPv4
     hwlen     = None
     plen      = None
     op        = who-has
     hwsrc     = 08:00:27:46:c6:d8
     psrc      = 10.0.2.7
     hwdst     = 00:00:00:00:00:00
     pdst      = 10.0.2.255


Process finished with exit code 0
```

Comment: Sorry I should have been more clear. Actually this was a bug in scapy 2.4.3 which has been resolved now.  And there's no such error in code as mentioned . An ip range can be given as input to scapy.ARP()